# Google Spreadsheet contains some text

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet and i want to create a function that write something in a cell if an already completed cell contains some text.
Ex: I have cell B that contains "Example A". I want to check if cell B contains "xam" and if it contains i want to write something in cell C.
Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:G1, "rmu"),"My Text",""))`

More info about `REGEXMATCH`: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098292
More info about `ARRAYFORMULA`: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093275

Answer (score 0):

Edited following @fooby comment.

To answer your specific question (a function that looks for a substring within a string in a defined cell):

```js
function testForXAM(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var value = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue().toUpperCase();

  if(value.indexOf('XAM') != -1){
    sheet.getRange('C1').setValue('something');
  }
}
```

As fooby states this is not expandable as is, but could be fairly easily.

Fooby's other point about using inbuilt formulae over script functions is very valid and an approach you should consider.

Comment: `indexOf()` does not return true if the substring is found. it returns the index of the first character of the first instance of the search string. For example, `'test'.indexOf('tes')`  will return `0`. `0` is a falsy and `0 == true` returns `false`. Also, the same search can be accomplished using regex `var regexp = /xam/i; if(regexp.test('string')) { //Write to other cell }`. Finally, as a matter of style, the function you have provided is not reusable at all, and there is much less over head using Spreadsheet formulas over custom scripts.